# Rails 3.2 error routing issue. Error ID is conflicting with other object ID

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, exception, routes, ruby-on-rails-3.2

We just upgraded our app to Rails 3.2.2 and are now having a routing issue for handling errors.

Per [José Valim's blog post](http://blog.plataformatec.com.br/2012/01/my-five-favorite-hidden-features-in-rails-3-2/), we added the following:
`config.exceptions_app = self.routes` to config/application.rb
`match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"` to config/routes.rb
(and the appropriate controller/views).

The problem is we need `ourdomain.com/id` to display an index page for a product category of `id`.

So, now `ourdomain.com/404` shows our 404 page, when it should show our category listing page for the category with an `id` of 404.

How can we work around this?
Is there a way to make the app prepend each error with `error_` before it's evaluated by `routes`?
Or, maybe somehow set `config.exceptions_app` to reference a namespace in the `routes` file?
Or, can I create a second route set and set `config.exceptions_app = self.second_set_of_routes`?

Thanks!

Comment: Why are the routes set to `/id` instead of `products/id`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's one solution which I've found so far:

```
# application_controller.rb

def rescue_404
  rescue_action_in_public CustomNotFoundError.new
end

def rescue_action_in_public(exception)
  case exception
    when CustomNotFoundError, ::ActionController::UnknownAction then
      #render_with_layout "shared/error404", 404, "standard"
      render template: "shared/error404", layout: "standard", status: "404"
    else
      @message = exception
      render template: "shared/error", layout: "standard", status: "500"
  end
end

def local_request?
  return false
end
```

`rescue_action_in_public` is the method that Rails calls to handle most errors.
`local_request?` the method tells Rails to stop sucking if it's local request

```
# config/routes.rb
match '*path', controller: 'application', action: 'rescue_404' \
  unless ::ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
```

It simply says that it can’t find any other route to handle the request (i.e. the `*path`) it should call the `rescue_404` action on the application controller (the first method above).

**EDIT**

This version worked for me well!
Try to add to `application.rb`

```
# 404 catch all route
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.routes.append{ match '*a', to: 'application#render_not_found' } \
    unless config.consider_all_requests_local
end
```

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671#issuecomment-1780159

Answer (score 4):

We had the same problem -- error codes colliding with ids for resources at the root level (e.g., collisions between `ourdomain.com/:resource_id` and `ourdomain.com/404`).

We modified José Valim's solution by adding a route constraint that only applies when handling an exception:

```
# Are we handling an exception?
class ExceptionAppConstraint
  def self.matches?(request)
    request.env["action_dispatch.exception"].present?
  end
end

MyApp::Application.routes.draw do
  # These routes are only considered when there is an exception
  constraints(ExceptionAppConstraint) do
    match "/404", :to => "errors#not_found"
    match "/500", :to => "errors#internal_server_error"

    # Any other status code
    match '*a', :to => "errors#unknown"
  end
  ...
  # other routes, including 'match "/:resource_id"'
end
```

(We only stumbled on this solution last night, so it hasn't had much burn-in time.  We are using Rails 3.2.8)

Answer (score 1):

It seems that this route is hard coded at the show_exceptions method ([see source](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/actionpack/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb#L45))

Sorry, but I don't think of a way of doing it besides changing the line 45 on the source above to:

```
env["PATH_INFO"] = "/error_#{status}"
```

(what is, needless to say, no solution at all).

It doesn't hurt to ask:If you thought it was nice to have your own error controller implemented so simply and desperately want to have it, than wouldn't it even be more "RESTful" if your route were yourdomain.com/product/:id?

Comment: You can patch it with an initializer.